# telerik radTreeListView UI Virtualization

Tags: telerik

Helle there,

I am using RadTreeListView control for loading big amount of data, it seems it doesnt suppot UI Virtualization, UI freezes and not responding at all.

The amount of data is 400 rows.

Do you have any ideas if it supports UI Virtualization?

-Amino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved, I had to add MinHeight="300" Height="550" to the RadTreeListView control